Usage of 'that's'
What is the grammatical usage of 'that's' in this sentence?

The best approach is to view deadlines as a challenge that you have to meet within a period that's imminent.


It's short for 'that is', with that being a relative pronoun referring to period. Personally I would say something like within a specified period.

It signals a restrictive clause that is specifying what kind of "period."

Is it possible to write in contraction of relative pronoun with verb like this? I'm asking of its commonality.

It’s quite natural and normal. I’ve got a mosquito bite that’s driving me crazy.


... have to meet within a period that's imminent.
... have to meet within a period that is imminent.

That's is a contraction of that is and it's describing the period as being imminent (soon; could happen at any time).
